# KeyboardInterrupt exeption handling with time.sleep

Tags: python, printing, try-catch, except, keyboardinterrupt

- I am going to display current time every 2 seconds and exception handling.
- If there is KeyboardInterrupt, message should display like print('Program is stopped').
  But in my code, try/except isn`t working.So how can I print message like 'Stopped'?

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def display_time():
    time.sleep(2)
    current_time = datetime.now()
    print('Time: ', current_time.strftime("%X"))

try:
    while True:
        display_time()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Stopped')
print('Program ends')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check if <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is pressed inside the `while` loop and, if so break outside the loop:

```py
while True:
    try:
        display_time()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopped")
        break

print('Program ends')
```